# Simulating correlated Geometric Brownian Motion with lag

Tags: time-series, correlation, simulations, geometric-brownian

I know that it is possible to simulate two correlated GBM in e.g. Matlab ([Generating Correlated Asset Paths in MATLAB](https://www.goddardconsulting.ca/matlab-monte-carlo-assetpaths-corr.html)) based on cholesky decomposition. However, they take as input the correlation matrix, which from my understanding is just the Pearson correlation coefficient. However, if I look at correlation between two time series, cross-correlation is the correct measure. This also results in a lag. Is it possible to incorporate the lag into the simulation of the correlated GBM?

Comment: Can you please explain what your ultimate aim is? Increments from the multivariate (G)BM are multivariate (log)normally distributed with an instantaneous correlation / covariance matrix. If you want to simulate lagged GBM, you could sample from a "true" GBM and then simply drop "unwanted" components.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, maybe you can simulate two correlated GBM's and then apply the lag manually afterward.

Comment: So in that case I suppose I should use the correlation coefficient from the maximum lag to simulate the two correlated GBMs?